# Java Continuous loop (loop without waiting)

Tags: java, iterator, while-loop

I would like to have a loop that runs continuously without waiting for the stuff in the loop. For example, in the example below, I would like to iterate a list and call a method called doSomething() and as soon as the doSomething() method is called, I would like the loop to continue to the second item, third item, so on…

```
 while(it.hasNext())
 {
    MyObject obj = (MyObject)it.next();
    doSomething(obj);
 }
```

It can be done with a poller but I don’t want to do it with the poller.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: In other words: you *don't* want to wait for `doSomething` to return before you start handling the next `obj`. Right?

Comment: implement `doSomething()` asynchronous

Comment: @JoachimSauer, yes you right.

Comment: 1) *"I would like to have a loop that runs continuously without waiting for the stuff in the loop."*  Why?  What is that intended to achieve? 2) What exactly is `doSomething(obj);` doing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to do this you need to run multiple threads, so the multiple calls can run in parallel. You can do this manually, but it's much better to use the existing utilities such as the [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html). This takes `Runnables` and runs them in parallel.

E.g.

```
// Create an executor that can run up to 10 jobs in parallel.
ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(10, 10, 5, TimeUnit.Seconds, new LinkedBlockingQueue());
while(it.hasNext()) {
    // NB: Final is needed so that this can be accessed within the anonymous inner class
    final MyObject obj = (MyObject)it.next();
    // Queue up the doSomething to be run by one of the 10 threads
    executor.execute(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            doSomething(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

With this code, all the loop does is schedule the execution of the doSomething method. After doing that, it proceeds to the next execution. The actual doSomething is run by one of the 10 threads managed by the `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

Answer (score 1):

I would normally recommend spawning a new thread which will 'doSomething' for you but it really depends what 'doSomething' does, how many objects are you going to iterate etc...